# Proof that two sets are equanimous, Proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that $X \cong Y$ from textbook which introduces uni maths.

Given
$X \cong \{1,\ldots , m\}$,

$Y \cong \{1, \ldots, n\}$,

$\{1,\ldots , m\} \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$.

*Proof*

Since $X \cong \{1,\ldots , m\}$ and $Y \cong \{1, \ldots, n\}$, then for every $a_i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ we have $x_i \in X$ and for every $b_i \in \{1,\ldots , n\}$ we have $y_i \in Y$ such that

$x_1 \neq x_2 \implies a_1 \neq a_2$,

$y_1 \neq y_2 \implies b_1 \neq b_2$ because of *bijectivity*.

Now since $\{1,\ldots , m\} \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$ and $X \cong \{1,\ldots , m\}$, by transitivity we have $X \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$. Same applies to $Y$. Therefore $X \cong Y$.

*Edit* as suggested by Hagen von Eitzen:

Given
$X \cong \{1,\ldots , m\}$,

$Y \cong \{1, \ldots, n\}$,

$\{1,\ldots , m\} \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$.

$\{1,\ldots , m\} \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$ and $X \cong \{1,\ldots , m\}$, by transitivity we have $X \cong \{1,\ldots , n\}$. Same applies to $Y$. Therefore $X \cong Y$.

Comment: If you are allowed to make use of transitivity and symmetry then it is immediate from the data that $X\cong Y$.

Comment: Isn't this just immediate from transitivity of $\cong$? Oops, I see you did just that. So just strike everything between "*Proof*" and "Now since", and your proof is fine (though *drhab* is right: You also need symmetry in one place)

Comment: What are equanimous sets?

Comment: @J.G. It means that there is bijection between the sets.

Comment: @flowian Boy, that has plenty of names. I've also heard it called being *equipollent* or *equinumerous*.

Comment: @J.G. My god. At least they all begin with *equ*.

Comment: @flowian I personally prefer equipollent, because we say a set is *infrapollent* to one it can be injected into; the other terms don't seem to have an infra- equivalent.